# mysqldump from a local machine, no ssh access to remote

Tags: ssh-tunnel, mysqldump

I can ssh to a a server (on a private network, via VPN connection), that has Apache installed on. Internal ip for this server is 192.168.10.98.
Web framework on this server can connect to MySQL server on 192.168.10.97.
Also I can connect to MySQL server, on a client app via SSH Tunnel, considering that I only have access to Apache server (192.168.10.98). 
I can dump db when I connect to MySQL on the client app.

[image: Connect to MySQL server]

Now, how can I ssh to Apache server, and use mysqldump on MySQL server to dump the db and save in on Apache server?

```
$apache_server> mysqldump -h 192.168.10.97 -uopencart -p opencart_db > ~/opencart_db.sql | gzip -c > db.zip
    -bash: mysqldump: command not found
```

If MySQL Client App can do this, I have to be able too?
But How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install `mysql-client` through your package manager on the Apache server. This will install mysqldump and allow you to dump directly on the Apache server using the command you listed.